# How to get array from list

Tags: php, loops

I have a problem for my program.

This my script:

```
$x=1;
$no=1;
$tot=0;
$bobot=0;
$jumlah=4;

for($i=1;$i<=$jumlah;$i++) {

<tr>
    <th> echo $no++; </th>

    for($a=$i;$a<=$jumlah;$a++) {
        echo "<td>".$x/$a."</td>";
    }
    <td>Count</td>
</tr>
}
```

and this is my result

[result page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD3rm.png)

I want to replace the words "count" with the sum of each column in the same row. and my question, how I can add all column in one rows.

example : row 1 = 1 + 0.5 + 0,33 + 0.25 = 2,08

Thank you for helping, I am sorry if my English so bad.

Comment: you cannot mix and mash PHP and HTML (e.g. `<tr>` should be `echo '<tr>'`) like you do. How does that give you the result you're showing? You should get _Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token_ etc.

Comment: Can you show us the structure of the array you're working on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

initialize $count as zero before the inner loop
and in inner loop increment county

```
  <?php
    $x=1;
    $no=1;
    $tot=0;
    $bobot=0;
    $jumlah=4;
    
    for($i=1;$i<=$jumlah;$i++) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <th> <?php echo $no++;?> </th>
        <?php
        $count=0;
        
        for($a=$i;$a<=$jumlah;$a++) {
            echo "<td>".$x/$a."</td>";
            $count=$count+($x/$a);
        }
        ?>
        <td><?=$count;?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```